# can't close uploaded file (suddenly)

Tags: php, file-upload

Suddenly these three lines throw the following error message. A few hours ago it just worked, I changed nothing within the file, I can read the file just fine and work with it.

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['xlsxFile'] ) ) {
    $tmp_file = 'tmp.xlsx';
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['xlsxFile']['tmp_name'], $tmp_file );

    fclose($tmp_file);
}
```

> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in
>   /var/www/vhosts/foo.bar/httpdocs/foo.php on line 5

It feels so weird for me, is there something, that might have changed on the hoster side or something?

Comment: you need to first open/read a file for `fclose()` to work http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php; why are you even using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to `fclose($tmp_file)` in that code example.  `fclose` is used to free resources held by a call to `fopen`.

`move_uploaded_file` just takes two strings that are the names of the files, and manages all the resources itself - you don't need to free the resources for that.

Comment: thank you for clarifying, I googled this, but it wasn't that clear. I will accept this, as soon, as I'm allowed to :)